# Is there a way to get rid of the *Heaviside(t) in my output?

Tags: python, sympy

I am trying to solve the equation:

X = (s*(s+1))/((s+2)*(s+3)*(s+4))

This is the code that I have tried:

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing()

s, t = sympy.symbols('s, t')

X = (s*(s+1))/((s+2)*(s+3)*(s+4))

parfrac = sympy.apart(X, full=True).doit()

def invL(parfrac):
    return sympy.inverse_laplace_transform(parfrac, s, t)

print('x(t) = ', invL(X))
```

This is my output:
x(t) =  (exp(2*t) - 6*exp(t) + 6)*exp(-4*t)*Heaviside(t)

How do I get rid of the Heaviside(t) out of the output?

Comment: if you define t > 0 you can just drop it. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside-Funktion

Comment: Yeah.  The Heaviside operator is just saying that the answer is different for `t > 0` and `t ≤ 0`.   

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function

Comment: If you just want to get rid of it then `expr.subs(Heaviside(t), 1)` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Working from the comments:

```
In [25]: t = symbols('t')

In [26]: invL(X)
Out[26]: 
⎛ 2⋅t      t    ⎞  -4⋅t     
⎝ℯ    - 6⋅ℯ  + 6⎠⋅ℯ    ⋅θ(t)

In [27]: t = symbols('t', positive=True)

In [28]: invL(X)
Out[28]: 
⎛ 2⋅t      t    ⎞  -4⋅t
⎝ℯ    - 6⋅ℯ  + 6⎠⋅ℯ
```